# F5 algorithm for non-regular sequences

Tags: symbolic-computation, groebner-basis

Faugère proves in his first Paper about the F5 algorithm the termination of the algorithm for regular sequences and mentions that some slight changes can be done to adapt this algorithm for non-regular sequences. I can find no following article of these adaptions and therefore no correctness proof. Does anyone know such a source or the ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[Eder and Faugère (2014)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.1774.pdf) give a very good summary of F5, provide (pointers to) proofs of correctnes and termination, and give an excellent survey of F5 variants, their interdependencies, and in which way they differ from the original F5 algorithm.